# WooCommerce disable billing address in wp-admin

Tags: php, wordpress

I have added this code to the Admin CSS plugin to hide the billing address fields on orders in wp-admin

```
#order_data .order_data_column_container .order_data_column:nth-child(2) .edit_address, 
#order_data .order_data_column_container .order_data_column:nth-child(2) .address, 
#order_data .order_data_column_container .order_data_column:nth-child(2) .address p, 
#order_data .order_data_column_container .order_data_column:nth-child(2) h3
{display:none}
```

it hides all of the billing address fields, however when you select a customer from the dropdown it is showing the fields again.

how can i stop these fields from showing completely even after a customer is selected